# quickblox new sdk integration

Tags: android, quickblox

I am trying to integrate last version of quickblox sdk

I have added these line to my gradle file

```
repositories {

jcenter()
flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
}
maven {
    url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
}
}
```

also add

```
сompile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-chat:3.3.1'
сompile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-content:3.3.1'
сompile 'com.quickblox:quickblox-android-sdk-messages:3.3.1'
```

now I am getting the following error when try to sync the gradle file

```
    Error:(151, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'сompile()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'app' may be using a version of the Android Gradle plug-in that does not contain the method (e.g. 'testCompile' was added in 1.1.0).
<a href="fixGradleElements">Upgrade plugin to version 2.3.1 and sync project</a></li><li>The project 'app' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="openGradleSettings">Gradle settings</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

can anyone told me please what is the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First check the sdk manager in android studio for updates ,like gradle .
then change code in gradle file and sync it.

```
maven {
    url "https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases/raw/master/"
}
```

to

```
maven {
            url= "file://Users/igor/workspace/quickblox/quickblox-android-sdk-releases-master"
        }
```

I hope it will work